# Basepoint of a pointed CW-complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Given a pointed CW-complex, is the basepoint always supposed to be a $0$-cell?

Comment: It doesn't have to be, but it "should" be.  It should also be well-pointed.

Comment: @ Randall: Thanks. I think that if the basepoint *is* a $0$-cell, then this pointed CW-complex is always well-pointed, isn't it?

Comment: It's usual to assume implicitly that a CW complex is pointed at some $0$-cell (although really this is a matter of taste). For instance then the basepoint will be a subcomplex and the inclusion map will be cellular. Note that if $X$ is a CW complex and $x_0\in X$, then $X$ admits a CW structure which has $x_0$ as a $0$-cell. Thus a CW complex is well-pointed when it is based at any point. Moreover, if $x_0,x_1\in X$ are two points in the same path-component of a CW complex $X$, then $(X,x_0)\simeq (X,x_1)$ as pointed spaces.

Comment: @ Tyrone: Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that, in a pointed CW-complex, the attaching maps should also be pointed. Otherwise, the basepoint may not be well-defined, or the characteristic maps not be pointed, so this wouldn't be a construction in the category of pointed topological spaces.

I would suggest defining a pointed CW-complex by changing the usual definition of CW-complex so that all spaces (spheres, disks) are pointed (with compatible basepoints, so the natural inclusions are pointed maps), all maps (inclusions, attaching maps) are also pointed, substitute disjoint unions by wedges, and choose basepoint $x_0 \in X_0$ **by definition**.

Then, a pointed topological space $(X,x_0)$ is a pointed CW-complex if there is a cell decomposition that satisfies the definition above. In particular, it must be the case that $x_0 \in X_0$.

One drawback is that there will be spaces that there are clearly CW-complexes but cannot be pointed CW-complexes, say a path graph with more than three points.

All boils down to the 'right' definition of pointed CW-complexes, which I cannot find.

Comment: An unpointed $CW$-complex is the disjoint union of its cells. Is a pointed $CW$-complex then the wedge-product of its cells?